# Validate html 4.01 tags with weblogic

Tags: html, weblogic, portal, bea

I need to validate a web application in html 4.01 transitional. In my project im working on skeletons/head.jsp to add meta tags. The problem is that i want to add tags like:

```
<meta name="robots" content="follow">
```

without the enclosing tag. And the document type is defined on skeleton.xml as HTML 4.01 Transitional. But when erase the slash the WorkShop Framework (Eclipse) fails if no exist ending tag.

It's the head.js where I have to put the meta tags?

Comment: I guess you are using WebLogic portal.

Answer (score 0):

> “But when erase the slash the program fails.”

I’m not familiar with WebLogic, but when you say “the program fails”, do you mean your website stops working? Or the resulting HTML page doesn’t validate?

Comment: ups, i mean: the workshop framework (Eclipse) fails because ending xml tag is not

Comment: Ah, okay. There’s your problem: HTML isn’t XML. I don’t suppose you can have the site validate as XHTML 1.0 Transitional instead, can you? It’s the same language as HTML 4.01 Transitional, just with XML syntax.